# How to combine two tables without duplicating rows, different granularity

Tags: sql, t-sql

There are two different Tables with different granularity (Type and SubType), I would like to combine both table for reporting purpose.
Cross join will multiply rows and I am avoiding UNION ALL as tables have more than 40 columns.

Tables

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
    SchoolID INT
    ,SchoolType INT
    ,SchoolSubtype INT
    ,SchoolScore INT
    ,LastUpdateDateTime DATETIME2
)


CREATE TABLE B
(
    SchoolID INT
    ,TotalStudents INT
    ,RecordedDate DATETIME2
)

INSERT INTO A (SchoolID, SchoolType, SchoolSubtype, SchoolScore, LastUpdateDateTime) 
VALUES (142, 342, 12, 98, '2019/12/01'), (142, 231, 11, 54, '2019/12/11'), (142, 231, 45, 89, '2019/12/01'), (145, 543, -1, 90, '2019/06/01')

INSERT INTO dbo.B (SchoolID, TotalStudents, RecordedDate)
VALUES (142, 82000,'2020/01/11'), (901, 78000,'2020/01/11')

SELECT *
FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT SchoolID, SchoolType, SchoolSubtype, 'A' AS [Source] FROM dbo.A
UNION ALL 
SELECT DISTINCT SchoolID, NULL AS SchoolType, NULL AS SchoolSubtype, 'B' AS [Source] FROM dbo.B
) AS z
    LEFT JOIN dbo.A
        ON z.SchoolID = a.SchoolID AND z.SchoolType = a.SchoolType AND z.SchoolSubtype = a.SchoolSubtype AND z.[Source] = 'A'
    LEFT JOIN dbo.B
        ON z.SchoolID = b.SchoolID AND z.[Source] = 'B'
```

Wanted Result

[image]

Comment: It would be more clear if you could share your current query and the problem you are facing with example?

Comment: 40*2 columns make no problem for `UNION [ALL]`

Comment: UNION ALL seems the obvious choice here, listing all columns in each SELECT, setting those that don’t exist in each table as NULL.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 Just updated question with Query I am using.

Comment: @Serg Actually A table has 40 and B has 90 columns.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent missing columns or any other misprint you may generate your `UNION ALL` from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`

```
declare @cmd varchar(max ) = 
    'select a.SchoolID'
    +
    (select ','+ c.COLUMN_NAME
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
    where c.TABLE_NAME = 'A'
        and c.COLUMN_NAME != 'SchoolID'
    for xml path('')
    )
    +
    (select ', null '+ c.COLUMN_NAME
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
    where c.TABLE_NAME = 'B'
        and c.COLUMN_NAME != 'SchoolID'
    for xml path('')
    )
    + 
    ' from A
    union all
    select b.SchoolID'
    +
    (select ', null '+ c.COLUMN_NAME
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
    where c.TABLE_NAME = 'A'
        and c.COLUMN_NAME != 'SchoolID'
    for xml path('')
    )
    +
    (select ','+ c.COLUMN_NAME
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
    where c.TABLE_NAME = 'B'
        and c.COLUMN_NAME != 'SchoolID'
    for xml path('')
    )
    + 
    ' from B
    order by SchoolID';

exec (@cmd);
```